# xsd attribute and element validation

Tags: xsd, attributes, element

I am trying to create an XSD schema which will validate the following xml.

```
<Item ItemGUID="3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301">The name of the item</Item>
```

I want to validate the max length of the attribute "ItemGUID" to 36 characters and "The name of the item" to a max 25 characters.

How can it be validated to satisfy the above condition using the xsd schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With XML Schema, you can do something like this:

```
<xs:element name="Item">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="string25">
        <xs:attribute name="ItemGUID" type="string36" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element> 

<xs:simpleType name="string25">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>


<xs:simpleType name="string36">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    <xs:maxLength value="36"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I haven't tried it, but if this doesn't work it should be very close to what you need.