# How do I defined an XSD attribute name as a regular expression?

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

The XML allows a variable number of attributes of Q followed by a number, like this

```
<recognitionPattern Q0="12.5" Q1="12.5" Q2="12.5" Q3="12.5" Q4="12.5" Q5="12.5" Q6="12.5" Q7="12.5"/>
```

My current solution looks something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="PerQuarterDoubleHack"> <!-- YUCK! /> -->
<xs:attribute name="Q0"                 type="xs:double"       />
<xs:attribute name="Q1"                 type="xs:double"       />
<xs:attribute name="Q2"                 type="xs:double"       />
<xs:attribute name="Q3"                 type="xs:double"       />
<xs:attribute name="Q4"                 type="xs:double"       />
<xs:attribute name="Q5"                 type="xs:double"       />
<xs:attribute name="Q6"                 type="xs:double"       />
<xs:attribute name="Q7"                 type="xs:double"       />
</xs:complexType>
```

I've seen lots of regular expressions applied to the value, but never an attribute name.
Do I have any choice than changing the XML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832542/xsd-attribute-and-element-validation

Answer (score 1):

XML Schema doesn't allow you to apply any validation to an attribute **name**, only its **value**. Your best bet is to change the XML, if possible, to something along these lines:

```
<recognitionPattern>
    <quarter id="0">12.55</quarter> <!-- equivalent to Q0 -->
    <quarter id="1">12.55</quarter> <!-- equivalent to Q1 -->
    <quarter id="2">12.55</quarter> <!-- equivalent to Q2 -->
    <quarter id="3">12.55</quarter> <!-- equivalent to Q3 -->
</recognitionPattern>
```

Comment: You can also validate the attribute name using custom code. For example, if you are using Java, you can set up a custom validation handler that gets called for each element of your XML.

Comment: Attributes can be validated. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832542/xsd-attribute-and-element-validation

Comment: Attribute *values* can indeed be validated. But what the OP is asking is the *name* of the attribute, *not* its content.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very poor XML design. Generally, XML processing tools assume that the application knows all the element and attribute names statically, and if this isn't the case, writing applications will be difficult. Change the design if you have the chance.