# Validate attribute names using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I would like to know if it is possible to validate attribute names by pattern using XML Schema. In other words, I would like to describe a set of acceptable attribute names for a given type, using a pattern (such as a regular expression).

Lets say I have the following XML data I would like to validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://mywebsite.com/myns">
  <somename data-someattr1="value1" 
            data-someattr2="value2"/>
</root>
```

How can I describe that attributes of elements with name *"somename"* can only have attributes with name beginning by *"data-"*? **Is this even possible?**

Comment: explains a little. it's free.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434098/how-do-i-defined-an-xsd-attribute-name-as-a-regular-expression

Comment: The reasons given for putting this question on hold do not apply; it's quite a specific question, with exactly two correct answers:  in XSD 1.0 the OP is out of luck, and in XSD 1.1 the OP can use assertions.  Oh, yes, and as Michael Kay points out in [the related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434098/how-do-i-defined-an-xsd-attribute-name-as-a-regular-expression), this is generally regarded as bad design.  (Its use in HTML 5, however, guarantees that it will come up again elsewhere.)

Comment: True, not achievable in XSD 1.0, @Jérôme, but the task is straightforward in XSD 1.1 with assertions:  add an attribute wildcard to the complex type, and add an assertion along the lines of `every $a in ./@* satisfies matches(name($n),'^(data-|att1$|att2$|...)')` (not tested -- replace att1, att2 with the names of your 'normal' non-data attributes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution! I did not test it yet but the approach seems very promising.

However, I'm wondering (because of the attribute wildcard) if it will make it if I want to specify some attributes for a particular namespace to be there + attributes beginning with "-data" to be there.

Answer (score 3):

Try something along the lines of:

```
<xs:simpleType name="somename">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="^data-"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The regex `^data-` means "beginning with 'data-'", as you require.

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood the question, sorry... Here is a more relevant answer:

As I understand it, you cannot pattern match attribute names in an XSD - so there is no solution to your problem using an XSD alone. However, you may find one of the following XML schema elements helpful in constructing a solution:

- XML choice (http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp) - so you could (possibly?) list all "data-" attribute names explicitly.
- XML any (http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp) - so you could then perform any additional validation steps via some other method.

Comment: Hi Tom Lord! Thanks for the time spent. Unfortunately, I am not satisfied with your answer because I am looking for validating attribute names, not their values!

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad! I guess I read your post too quickly and misunderstood the question. I've added a more relevant answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it was said you can't validate attribute names, but you still can go different way and transform your xml to some kind of:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <data name='data-attr1' value='v1'/>
        <data name='data-attr2' value='v2'/>
        <data name='data-attr3' value='v3'/>
    </element>
</root>
```

So now you can validate *fake* attribute name - `data name='data-attr1'` as well as values. Your schema might look like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' elementFormDefault='qualified' attributeFormDefault='unqualified'>
    <xs:element name='root'>
        <xs:complexType>            
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name='element'>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs='10' name='data'>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name='name' use='required'>
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
                                                <xs:pattern value='data-.*' />
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name='value' use='required' />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```